# I'm trying to resize the image using opencv in google colab but it's throwing error

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize the image but it's throwing error in google colab.

```
images = cv2.imread('uk-dl.jpg')
image_resize = cv2.resize(images, (4600, 5500))
cv2.imwrite(images, image_resize)
```

**Error is:**

```
SystemError: <built-in function imwrite> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Answer (score 1):

you did a minor syntax mistake

Syntax: `cv2.imwrite(filename, image)`

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

images = cv2.imread('/Images/copy.jpg')

image_resize = cv2.resize(images, (4600, 5500))

cv2_imshow(imgResize)

#cv2.imwrite(images, image_resize)==> you should use like this format (img='face.jpg'---> cv2.imwrite(img,image_resize))

cv2.imwrite('face.jpg', imgResize) # you can use directly
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this image processing notebook for further details:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1b8pVMMoR37a3b9ICo8TMqMLVD-WvbzTk#scrollTo=YcL2ZCWyDF2U

your code is perfect for jupyter notebook as per my understanding but when you use online google Colab you should define from where you are taking or uploading the photo and where you want to download or save it. define the perfect destinations and your code should work or you can refer the notebook which has code for resizing multiple images on google Colab.

Also, see the another file for how to mount google drive with Colab.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YKHHLSlG-B9Ez2-zf-YFxXTVgfC_Aqtt

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that once.